# Linq to DataSet filter one column for multi keywords

Tags: c#, where-clause, linq-to-dataset

I have code like this:

```
 var modele = from model in ds.Tables["modele"].AsEnumerable()
                         where model.Field<string>("KRAJ_PRODUKCJI") == krajText
                         && model.Field<string>("FABRYKA") == fabrykaText
                        // && model.Field<string>("NAZWA") == itemId 
                         orderby model.Field<string>("NAZWA")
                         select model;
```

In the commented out line I need to dynamically generate a `where` clause or check that the field `NAZWA` is equal to one of multiple keyword in `itemId` which is a list with a few keyword to check with || between.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like:

```
where itemId.Contains(model.Field<string>("NAZWA"))
```

I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for, but it might be.

@korchev's won't work because you want an "||".

Mam nadzieje ze to pomocne.

Comment: Indeed, I was thinking the same thing and saw your answer being added whilst typing mine. :) Possibly this is the easiest approach.

Comment: What kind of data structure is itemId? (Jakie struktura jest 'itemId'? Jesli jest 'string', to bedzies musil uzywac 'Split()')

Comment: itemId id List<string>. Cpfohl your Polish is good, You have Polish roots ? ;)

Comment: What happens when you *just* do: `from model in ds.Tables["modele"].AsEnumerable() where itemId.Contains(model.Field<string>("NAZWA")` ?

Answer (score 0):

Might not work straight out-of-the-box, but I'm guessing you should look for your answer in this direction:

```
var keywords = itemId.split("||");

var model = from m in ds.Tables["modele"].AsQueryable();

model = model.Where(m => keywords.Contains(m.Field<string>("NAZWA"));
```